# I want to open a modal on a separate page by clicking on a button which is on other page. This all is to be done using bootstrap. Is this possible

Tags: javascript, java, bootstrap-4

Like on Click on Sign up button (in Signup.jsp) A modal should be opened with a message of Congratulations and a button of Login So that we will redirect to Login page

Comment: Modal are meant to open in same page

Comment: ..also how should one click on a button which is on another page? Either your question is not clear or it makes no sense (or I need more coffee)

Comment: You can use long polling to react to changes made by another page. This means to use `setInterval` to schedule Ajax requests, and then navigate elsewhere like you want to.